# Write spark dataframe to file using python and '|' delimiter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have constructed a Spark dataframe from a query. What I wish to do is print the dataframe to a text file with all information delimited by '|', like the following:

```
+-------+----+----+----+
|Summary|col1|col2|col3|
+-------+----+----+----+
|row1   |1   |14  |17  |
|row2   |3   |12  |2343|
+-------+----+----+----+
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try to write to csv choosing a delimiter of |

```
df.write.option("sep","|").option("header","true").csv(filename)
```

This would not be 100% the same but would be close.

Alternatively you can collect to the driver and do it youself e.g.:

```
myprint(df.collect())
```

or

```
myprint(df.take(100))
```

df.collect and df.take return a list of rows.

Lastly you can collect to the driver using topandas and use pandas tools

Answer (score 6):

In **Spark 2.0+**, you can use in-built CSV writer. Here `delimiter` is `,` by default and you can set it to `|`

```
df.write \
    .format('csv') \
    .options(delimiter='|') \
    .save('target/location')
```